# Reshape data table from horizon to vertical and sum in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data table like this:

```
df<-data.frame("Date"=c("2010-05-27","2010-05-27","2010-07-08","2010-07-09","2010-07-09"),"Access1"=c(5,5,NA,7,7),"Access2"=c(6,6,NA,7,7),"Hour1"=c(0.55,0.55,NA,0.01,0.01),"Hour2"=c(0.55,0.55,NA,0.01,0.01))
    Date       Access1 Access2 Hour1 Hour2
1 2010-05-27       5       6  0.55  0.55
2 2010-05-27       5       6  0.55  0.55
3 2010-07-08      NA      NA    NA    NA
4 2010-07-09       7       7  0.01  0.01
5 2010-07-09       7       7  0.01  0.01
```

I want to reshape it to vertical table and sum `Hour` by `Access` and `Date`  like this

```
     Date    Access Hour
1 2010-05-27      5 1.10
2 2010-05-27      6 1.10
3 2010-07-08     NA   NA
4 2010-07-09      7 0.04
```

I tried with `gather` and `melt`, but it doesn't work. Can you suggest me a way to solve it?

Comment: Why `Hour1` and `Hour2` are summed for `2010-05-27` but not for `Access1` and `Access2`

Comment: Because I want to how many hour should spend on each Access number per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2) ; library(dplyr) 
dat <- melt(df, id= c("Date", "Hour1", "Hour2")) %>% #melt "Accesses" only
     mutate(sumHour = Hour1 + Hour2) %>% #sum "Hours"
     distinct() %>% 
     group_by(Date, value) %>% 
     summarise(Hour = sum(sumHour)) %>% 
     rename(Access = value) %>%  #rename for wanted output
     arrange(Date)  #order by date
```

This should give you the wanted ouput.

Comment: the `Hour` output is correct but the `Date` is duplicated

Comment: The sum only applies for `Access` right, not include `Date` 
Sorry, the last day should be 0.04, I edited my example

Comment: Sorry, the distinct was actually at its right place. i made sure the output is the same as the one you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my solution but now it should work. I simply cut the two columns Access2 and Hour2 and put them as additional rows before the summation.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(Date, Access = Access1, Hour = Hour1) %>%
  rbind(df %>% select(Date, Access = Access2, Hour = Hour2)) %>%
  group_by(Date,Access) %>%
  summarise(Hour = sum(Hour))
```

Comment: @tom Seems like we both ran into the same problem but I have fixed it for my version as well. Nice to know there at least two viable solutions.

Comment: It works in my example. Thank you.
But if I have 10 `Access` columns and 10 `Hour` columns. I have to do `rbind` for 10 times?

Comment: @Jenny Pham yes so tom's solutions is certainly more efficient. But for a simple problem with less columns this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k, v, -Date, -rowname) %>% 
  separate(k, into = c("type", "num"), sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
  spread(type, v) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Access) %>% 
  summarise(Hour = sum(Hour))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Date [3]
  Date       Access  Hour
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 2010-05-27      5  1.1 
2 2010-05-27      6  1.1 
3 2010-07-08     NA NA   
4 2010-07-09      7  0.04
```